# Paste Range of filtered data in columns in the same order/format

Tags: excel, vba

I have the working code below that copies filtered data to filtered cells when I select data from one column.

When I try a range of multiple columns it copies the data back in a single column and pastes is like so: column1V1, column1V2, column1V3, etc

How can I paste the filtered data in the same order/format in other columns?

```
Sub Filtered_Cells()

    Dim from As Range

    Set from = Application.InputBox("Select range to copy selected cells to", Type:=8)

    from.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Call Copy_Filtered_Cells

End Sub

Sub Copy_Filtered_Cells()

    Set from = Selection
    Set too = Application.InputBox("Select range to copy selected cells to", Type:=8)

    For Each Cell In from
        Cell.Copy
        For Each thing In too
            If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
                thing.PasteSpecial
                Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you highlight which line is showing you the error ?

Comment: Hi! There is no error involved. It works fine. I want to expand on its functionality so it can copy multiple data from multiple columns and paste it to other columns in the same format/order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user FAB i was able to further develop the macro. Now it copies without any limitations or problems any range of visible cells to any visible data. The problem was the array not being able to "record" more then 18-or-so elements. I used the trick of copying the user-selected data to a new sheet, which could be attributed successfully to the array.
Here is the finished code.

```
Public copyRng As Range
Public wb As Workbook

Sub Copy_Paste_Filtered_Data()

Copy

Dim from As Range, too As Range, fromRng As Range
Set from = copyRng
Set too = Application.InputBox("Select range to paste cells to", Type:=8)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = from.Worksheet
Dim arrRanges() As String: arrRanges = Split(from.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address, ",")

Dim R As Long, X As Long, nextVisRow As Long

    For X = LBound(arrRanges) To UBound(arrRanges)  'For each visible range
        Set fromRng = ws.Range(arrRanges(X))
        With fromRng
            For R = 1 To .Rows.Count  'For each row in the selected range
                nextVisRow = NextVisibleRow(too.Cells(1, 1)) 'Get the next visible row for paste

                too.Offset(nextVisRow - too.Row).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value = .Offset(R - 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value
                Set too = too.Offset(nextVisRow - too.Row + 1)
            Next R
        End With
    Next X

wb.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Function NextVisibleRow(rng As Range) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rng.Worksheet
Dim R As Long: R = rng.Cells(1, 1).Row

    Do While True
        If Not ws.Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden Then
            NextVisibleRow = R
            Exit Do
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Loop

End Function

Public Function Copy()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB")
Set copyRng = Application.InputBox("Select range to copy cells from", Type:=8)
copyRng.Select
Selection.Copy
    With wb
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            ws.Name = "Temp"
    End With
wb.Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set copyRng = Selection

End Function
```

This uses the "PERSONAL.XLSB" workbook, so be sure to record in it a macro first, to activate it, before using this Macro

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```vb
Sub Copy_Filtered_Cells_New()

Dim from As Range, too As Range, fromRng As Range
Set from = Application.InputBox("Select range to copy cells from", Type:=8)
Set too = Application.InputBox("Select range to paste cells to", Type:=8)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = from.Worksheet
Dim arrRanges() As String: arrRanges = Split(from.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).address, ",")

Dim R As Long, X As Long, nextVisRow As Long

    For X = LBound(arrRanges) To UBound(arrRanges)  'For each visible range
        Set fromRng = ws.Range(arrRanges(X))
        With fromRng
            For R = 1 To .Rows.Count  'For each row in the selected range
                nextVisRow = NextVisibleRow(too.Cells(1, 1)) 'Get the next visible row for paste

                too.Offset(nextVisRow - too.row).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value = .Offset(R - 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value
                Set too = too.Offset(nextVisRow - too.row + 1)
            Next R
        End With
    Next X

End Sub

Function NextVisibleRow(rng As Range) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rng.Worksheet
Dim R As Long: R = rng.Cells(1, 1).row

    Do While True
        If Not ws.Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden Then
            NextVisibleRow = R
            Exit Do
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: This is great and almost works as exected. It copies the filtered data successfully, but when the paste happens it goes under the filter

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT!! Works exactly as indended. Thank you!!

Comment: Is there a way to expand it's 'memory?'. For example, if there are lots of data, it does copy-paste everything, up to a point.

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve can be done better in other ways, I've rewrote the code to be as close as possible to yours. Not sure what the limitations are in the selected range... how much is `lots of data` in your view? Also, this ranges you are copying from/too ... are on the same level (i.e.: copy from "A1:A200" to "X1:X200"? And why it needs to be copied over hidden rows? The point is, there are more efficient ways to deal with the data, and will surely support "lots of data" if done right.

Comment: It's work related and the goal was to improve the time wasted on copying and pasting filtered cells, since the work implies the we often work with filters. Lots of data can mean 2000 cells for example. The ranges are not always on the same level, but copying cells from visible range to visible range is often needed

Comment: I can understand the need to copy only certain rows, but don't quite get why paste over other hidden rows (and only on the visible rows...)... i mean no ofense, just don't see a reasonable application for that. 2000 cells should be no problem memory wise though, maybe something else is going wrong (might need some tweaking in the code). Try to step through the code (`F8`) and see where is going amiss.. PS: if you are looking at automating some of that work, see if you can decide your ranges (manually or dynamically) without the need of `InputBox`.